# Integrals and Residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to find the integrals of $e^z/(z^2+1)$ around the circle $|z|=2$ traversed once in the positive sense.

I used the triangle inequality to find the upper bound but don't know how to calculate the integral directly. The upper bound I have is $4\pi e^2/3$. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need an upper bound. In the title you mention the residue theorem. Use that.

Comment: But if I calculate it directly, I get a extremely difficult result, which is $1/(2\pi i)( -1/2 i e{-i} (e^{2 i} Ei(-i+z)-Ei(i+z)))$

Comment: That's entirely wrong. You should get $2\pi i \sin 1$.

Comment: How did you get that answer?

Comment: What does the residue theorem say $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} f(z)\,dz$$ is, if $f$ is a meromorphic function having no pole on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = r$?

Comment: It's gonna be 0?

Comment: No. Look at the statement of the residue theorem again.