# Prove the sum of residues are zero

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am learning Laurent series, and I've learnt residue theorem before, but I am trying to solve a problem and get stuck here:

Suppose $f:\Bbb C \ (p_1, ..., p_n)$ → $\Bbb C$ is holomorphic (i.e. it only has a finitely many isolated singularities). Then how to show that $\sum^n_{j=1} Res_{p_j}f(z)+Res_\infty f(z)=0$

Comment: Every small circle is the boundary of _two_ domains in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. Apply the residue theorem to both domains.

Comment: So I'll get that each of them is 0, so the sum is gonna be zero. Is that correct?

Comment: No. If all residues were $0$, residues wouldn't be useful at all. With the given condition, the sum of the residues is $0$, but any individual residue would rarely be $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) is defined by $$Res(f(z),\infty) = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{-1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = R} f(z)dz \overset{s = 1/z}= \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{-1}{2i\pi} \int_{|s| = 1/R} \frac{f(1/s)}{s^2}ds = Res(\frac{-f(1/z)}{z^2},0)$$ Now by the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)$$ \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = R} f(z)dz = \sum_{|p_j| < R} Res(f(z),p_j)$$  You get  that $$\sum_j Res(f(z),p_j)+Res(f(z),\infty) = 0$$

Comment: Could you also look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984937/integrals-and-residue-theorem?noredirect=1#comment4075075_1984937, I still don't get it.

Comment: @J.doe What don't you understand in what I wrote ? The rest is how to compute a residue.

Comment: Nope, I got this problem. I have another question about residue theorem, and I hope maybe you can take a look at it and offer some help, if it is possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain why there is a s^2 in the denominator? It's must be something with dz=d(1/s) I suppose.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think in one of those steps there should not be a minus sign (I think after the first equal-sign).